# What's a good introductory book for Chaos/Dynamical systems/Fractals in Pure Mathematics?

Tags: dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, fractals, chaos-theory

For someone with a Masters degree in pure mathematics?

Comment: First off, Fractals and Dynamical Systems are two very different subjects while Chaos might be viewed as a sub-topic of Dynamical Systems. Furthermore, both subjects are quite broad - particularly Dynamical Systems. So I think you'd really need to focus the question quite a lot to get a reasonable response.

Answer (score 1):

I could recommend Glendinning's [Stability, Instability and Chaos.](http://goo.gl/bK6cx6)

Will go into quite some detail about dynamical systems and chaos, though not fractals. This book was closely related to a course I took which is why I recommend it, though I have not studied it in detail.

A great Math.SE thread covering book requests for Dynamical Systems, which mentions the above book, is [Recommendation for a book and other material on dynamical systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56958/recommendation-for-a-book-and-other-material-on-dynamical-systems?rq=1)